# How to create a notification for other apps in android?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'd like to know if it is possible in Android 4.3+ to have an app which can create a notification of **another** app.

*For example:* I develop an app, say myApp, with a button. Every time I tap on that button a new notification from another app, say Telegram, is triggered.

I'm sorry I don't have any code to show you as a start point nor a POC, but I really can't find anything useful on the web.

Comment: "a new notification from another app, say Telegram, is triggered" -- what do you mean by this?

Comment: When you press button in your app how other app is giving notification. Is your app updating something so other get trigger to notify.

Comment: I can't update nothing. I have to force another app to trigger it's own notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible. Unless you have some communication channel that generates a new notification. For example:

- You have developed a messaging app X that when receives a message produces a notification.
- You have developed an application Y that sends a message to the application X.

Answer (score 0):

You can pop a noti  with whatever info you want. But you want to say, notify of a new mms or gmail, then no